# What is the difference between "delete" and "recommend deletion" votes?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

I can't quite get how the Low Quality queue works.

How many delete votes are needed to delete an answer and is any "Recommend deletion" votes are enough?

And what is the difference between these votes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposedly, the low quality review queue allows you to vote to delete (a 20k privilege) 0 scored answers from the review, in hopes this [speed up the deletion process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230873/213575). If 3 20ker users vote to delete an answer, it will be deleted (even if the score isn't -1 or less), otherwise your delete vote will count as a "recommend deletion" vote, in which case 6 are necessary.